# How to display enabled applications using pure sql query?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables in my database with following structure

**Applications enabled**

```
CREATE TABLE `applications_enabled` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `application_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `organization_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `application_id` (`application_id`),
  KEY `organization_id` (`organization_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `applications_enabled_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`application_id`) REFERENCES `applications` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `applications_enabled_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`organization_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=15 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

**List of Applications**

```
CREATE TABLE `applications` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_public` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `content` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `logo` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `namespace` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=11 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Now applications are enabled on `organization` basis as reflected in `applications_enabled` database with reference to `organization_id` and `application_id` enabled.

What i want is a single query to list out all the applications listed in `applications` table with a field set if they are enabled or not for a particular organization.

The current sql query that i have come so far is

```
SELECT
  *
FROM applications
LEFT JOIN applications_enabled
  ON applications.id = applications_enabled.application_id
WHERE applications_enabled.organization_id = 89
OR applications_enabled.organization_id IS NULL;
```

Which worked fine while i was testing, but then i noticed that as we had more data, if another `organization` already enabled that `application` then the `organization_id` was not set to `NULL` and there were `applications` missing. What would be the correct sql query for that ?

Answer (score 1):

If you get this list per organization then I'd suggest going the other way around. Check for any applications_enabled first and then join those results with the actual application:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    applications_enabled
        INNER JOIN
    applications ON applications_enabled.application_id = applications.id
WHERE
    applications_enabled.organization_id = 89;
```